# Using .sass extension files on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sass, bulma, web-compiler

I am using Web Compiler extension to compile from scss files to css on Visual Studio 2019, and it works fine.

However, when trying to incorporate bulma css framework that uses .sass extension files it seems not to recognize these files.

Do you know if there is a simple way to compile .sass extension files to .css on Visual Studio 2019??

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting .net core 3.1, you can use JacobDixon.AspNetCore.LiveSassCompile.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JacobDixon.AspNetCore.LiveSassCompile

It compiles sass/scss files on startup and while the server is running.

Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently attempting the same thing: use Bulma with Visual Studio 2019 and Web Compiler. The SASS files do not get compiled by default because they were not added to the "compilerconfig.json" file as required by Web Compiler.
So you have to right-click each Bulma SASS file and select "Web Compiler" --> "Compile file". This will add it to the .json file and create/compile a .css file. 
For Bulma specifically, you pnly have to compile the "main" Bulma.css file in the parent folder of the source code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one for syntax highlight

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented

this is for beatify

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier

Comment: I understand those are for Visual Studio Code, for Visual Studio Community (2019) do you know if there is an extension that allow me compile .sass extension files?? (no scss but sass extension)